# Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to parse this data from Marvel API by using `JSON.parse();` but I am not able to. I am using Node.js.

Here is the code which I am using to get data from the api:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const nameStartsWith = req.body.superhero;
  const ts = "timestamp";
  const apikey = "myPublicKey";
  const hash = "md5 digest";
  const url = "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=" + ts + 
              "&apikey=" + apikey + "&hash=" + hash + "&nameStartsWith=" 
              + nameStartsWith;

  http.get(url, function(response) {

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      // getting error here
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });
});
```

Below is the incomplete JSON data:

```
    {"code":200,"status":"Ok","copyright":"© 2022 MARVEL","attributionText":"Data provided by Marvel. © 2022 MARVEL","attributionHTML":"<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2022 MARVEL</a>","etag":"08aea880d9e638f37cf6011d63a936fbe3f82f22","data":{"offset":0,"limit":20,"total":5,"count":5,"results":[{"id":1009718,"name":"Wolverine","description":"Born with super-human senses and the power to heal from almost any wound, Wolverine was captured by a secret Canadian organization and given an unbreakable skeleton and claws. Treated like an animal, it took years for him to control himself. Now, he's a premiere member of both the X-Men and the Avengers.","modified":"2016-05-02T12:21:44-0400","thumbnail":{"path":"http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/2/60/537bcaef0f6cf","extension":"jpg"},"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009718","comics":{"available":2549,"collectionURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1009718/comics","items":[{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/41113","name":"5 Ronin (Hardcover)"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/38756","name":"5 Ronin (2010) #1"
```

It is showing this error in my hyper terminal:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mishr\OneDrive\Desktop\MarvelComics-Project\app.js:79:24)
```

Comment: Would you care to share a bit more of your code?

Comment: We can't determine what the issue is unless we have more code or even a sample of what the API looks like. as this issue could be related to a few things within your codebase or the API

Comment: I've edited my question. Will this help in finding the solution?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data returned? Also, try to console.log the data without parsing it and use an online json tool to validate it.

Comment: If i try to console.log the data without parsing it then i can see a bunch of hexa decimal data and the point is to use that data into my project dynamically. For example if you'll see that incomplete json it gives info about wolverine. So what if someone uses my app to get data about spiderman? I should show them the related data in a formatted manner on my website so that they will be able to comprehend. So how can I use an online tool to validate the data everytime when a user uses my web app? Get what I am trying to do?